# Query String validation Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know how to get the query string array to validate in Laravel Validation.

here is my code

```
 public function addUserByAdmin(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name' => 'required',
        'fullname' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        'position' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required'
    ]);
        $uesrAction = new UserAction($this->repository);
        $user = $uesrAction->addUser($request->input('phone'),$request->input('password'),$request->input('name'),$request->input('fullname'),$request->input('position'));
        if($user){
            return response()->json(['success' => 'success','user'=>$user]);
        }
        return response()->json(['success' => 'fail']);
}
```

but validation doesn't work.Then I tried Validation::make() method and also didn't work.

My URL be like

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/users/add-user?phone=abcdefg&password=erer&name=ere&fullname=rere&position=343
```

Comment: what's your exact problem?? Validation should works fine here.

Comment: what do you mean by 'doesnt work'? what are you expecting to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: `password` in the URL?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using laravel 5.5, change your code as follows:

```
public function addUserByAdmin(Request $request){

    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'fullname' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        'position' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required'
    ]);

    // ...
}
```

One of the features that was added in this update is that other way to use the **validate()** method:

More info:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/releases